# Type mismatch error when type is not defined in abstract class

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and got stuck with a compiler error from below code. I am trying to implement a Natural number class which represents +ve integers. I am facing problem while defining the + operator which should follow, `def + (that: Nat): Nat` but I don't define this in abstract class I get below error. But it goes away once it is defined in the abstract class.

```
[error] D:\Scala\NatuarlNum\src\main\scala\NatuarlNum.scala:31:46: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Nat
[error]  required: String
[error]   def + (that: Nat): Nat = new Succ(previous.+(that))
```

I am not able to understand why it says required is "String" instead of "Nat". even when the function declaration is present just before the definition.

**Here is the code:**

```
abstract class Nat {
  def isZero: Boolean
  def predecessor: Nat
  def successor: Nat
  //def + (that: Nat): Nat  // By uncommentng this line the error will go away
  //def - (that: Nat): Nat
  override def toString: String = {
    if (this.isZero) {
      "0"
    } else {
      "{" + this.predecessor.toString + "}"
    }
  }
}

object Zero extends Nat {
  def isZero = true
  def predecessor = throw new Error("0.predecessor")
  def successor: Nat = new Succ(this)
  def + (that: Nat): Nat = that
}

class Succ(previous: Nat) extends Nat {
  def isZero = false
  def predecessor = previous
  def successor: Nat = new Succ(this)
  def + (that: Nat): Nat = new Succ(previous.+(that))  // The error is from this line
}

object NatuarlNum {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val zero = Zero
    val one = new Succ(zero)
    val two = new Succ(one)
    val three = new Succ(new Succ(new Succ(Zero)))

    println("0 = " + zero)
    println("1 = " + one)
    println("2 = " + two)
    println("3 = " + three)

    println("0 + 2 = " + (zero + two))
    println("2 + 2 = " + (two + two))   

  }
}
```

Without the + operator my code compiles and gives result like this:

```
0 = 0
1 = {0}
2 = {{0}}
3 = {{{0}}}
0 + 2 = {{0}}
```

Comment: A type will only expose the operations present in itself. It doesn't matter if one or any of all the subtypes of it has some function, that is not proof that supertype will have it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you gave an answer to your question in your code.

```
  //def + (that: Nat): Nat  // By uncommentng this line the error will go away
  //def - (that: Nat): Nat
```

The problem is,

```
def + (that: Nat): Nat = new Succ(previous.+(that))
```

`previous` is of type `Nat`, which doesn't have `+` operator override.

If you uncomment the definition for operators in `Nat` - it will work.

The default implementation of `+` operator takes `String` as a parameter, which explains the error message you get, see [any2stringadd](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Predef$$any2stringadd.html) for more info and there is a [ticket](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/194) to remove implicit `+` operator definition.

From compiler warning:

> Predef is deprecated (since 2.13.0): Implicit injection of + is deprecated. Convert to String to call +